# Add a discount to a product with Rules

Tags: commerce

I want to add a new *price field* called *Discount* to a product. So now I have two price fields, *Price* and *Discount*.

Then with the help of the rule, I am interested in showing in the *node page* the price(with line-trough) and the discount.

Then when adding the product to the cart, the discount price will be added, instead of the normal price. How can I achieve this with rules?

PS: I don't want to use the [Commerce Sale price](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_saleprice) module since it doesn't integrate with [Search api](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api).

I have found these instructions but I am not sure how to create the rule!

1. Add another price field to your product type.
2. Add a rule that applies the discount to the price on that product if the extra price field exists. Make sure you use the *Discount* price component when creating the rule.
3. Use Extra Price Formatters to display the difference.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution:I cloned the rule of the Commerce Sale module:
I created a Component:
Conditions:
-Entity has field:Parameter: Entity: [line-item], Field: commerce_product
-Entity has field:Parameter: Entity: [line-item:commerce-product], Field: field_discount_price
-NOT Data value is empty:line-item:commerce-product:field-discount-price:amount

Actions:Set the unit price to a specific amount 
(Specify the numeric amount to set the price to:Price:Amount
Value:Discount

Then I created a rule:
Events:Calculating the sell price of a product
Action:The previous component
(Data selector:Commerce line items)

Then I used a price formatter and its done https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_extra_price_formatters
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case and tried to build the rule as you described. At start I did not get it right but then I looked into the component setup here:
[Commerce Saleprice rules code](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/commerce_saleprice/tree/commerce_saleprice.rules_defaults.inc)

I used this module to manage the formatters: [Drupal Commerce Extra Price Formatters](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_extra_price_formatters)

I added a Discount field to my product fields and a Rule to calculate price using the above component. I also went for a % instead of using a final price so I used the Multiply option.